# How to extract values from this complex Puppet Struct

Tags: puppet

I have this data structure in puppet:

```
Struct[
    'ssh_keys' => Hash[
      String,
      Struct[
        'path'    => String,
        'content' => String,
      ]
    ]
  ] $myStructure
```

And I would like to extract all the 'path' values into an Array.

I got as far as mapping the inner Struct using

```
$testvariable = $myStructure['ssh_keys'].map |$items| { $items[1] }
```

But a bit suck here, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what you're hung up on, as you are indeed most of the way to a solution that should work.  For hashes, however, I do usually prefer the form of the `map()` function in which the lambda takes two parameters, a separate key and value.  That will read more clearly in this case:

```
$testvariable = $myStructure['ssh_keys'].map |$unused, $ssh_key| { $ssh_key['path'] }
```

But you should also be able in your original code to index `$items[1]` as the hash (`Struct`) it is: `$items[1]['path']`.

You could also use the [`dig()`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.4/function.html#dig) function if you cannot abide the mixture of array and hash indexing in the above: `$items.dig(1, 'path')`.

Comment: I would also mention, don't use camelCase in Puppet. See e.g. https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet/issues/622 See also style guide. Also a bunch of other bugs seen in the past relating to camel case.